# Rename editor tabs in DataGrip

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dbeaver, datagrip

I'm trying to figure out how to rename the editor tabs in DataGrip to be more accurate. I could not find a way to do it and cannot imagine that DataGrip does not offer such an important feature. I am probably missing it somewhere.

Here's a screenshot of my databases on DataGrip vs DBeaver.

[image: DataGrip DB]

[image: DBeaver DB]

What I am trying to change is the name of the editor tab as soon as I open the query console. At the moment it looks like this in DataGrip vs in DBeaver.

[image: DataGrip]

[image: DBeaver]

I would like to be able to always exactly know on which Database I am, an DBeaver offers that under the Script preferences as **Script Title Pattern**. There you're able to define yourself what your script tabs should look like.

e.g.

```
<${connectionName}>${database}@${schema}: ${fileName}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is now impossible. The issue is created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13984

Comment: Great, let's see if we get lucky. Dbeaver actually implemented that once I asked!
There's also this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13981

Answer (score 1):

Should be standard procedure and I know [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) supports it. I saw a ticket created for it in GitHub. Use that until JetBrains solves the issue.